# Finding contacts in Group A AND Group B?

Tags: groups

It seems like there must be a way to search for (and hopefully perform group operations on)contacts that are in both Group A AND Group B but I can't find it.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 12):

You can use Search Builder (Search > Search Builder) to search for contacts in a group A and add another search field for contacts in Group B. See screenshot from [demo](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1).

[image: 2Groups Screenshot]

Comment: Would highly recommend using the "IN" operator instead of "=".

Answer (score 3):

Under Search > Custom Search there is a search called Include / Exclude Search which is specifically for this purpose ie including/excluding specific Tags and Groups. You can see it here on the [demo site](http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=4&reset=1).

I don't know if it delivers what you need but worth knowing about.