# Trying to do a search using tags

Tags: search, tags

I have tags set in my database. A few that I want to search by are D1 School, D1AA School and Recruiter. I want to find all contacts that have D1AA School and Recruiter checked off but I can't find any search that does 'and' and it only does 'or'. That gives me any contact that has D1AA School or Recruiter checked. I am trying to create groups based on the tags so I can do a mailing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Search Builder (Search menu item > Search builder; see this answer about [searching for Groups A and B](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8132/105), it's the same concept) or a [custom include/exclude search](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/8136/105).

Once you have the search results, you can add the resulting contacts to a group for your mailing.